# Select just first line of chars up to CR/LF from a text column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to select or substring just the first line of chars in a SQL Server text column, to then prepend as the first line of chars in another text field in another table?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running SQL Server 2005 or higher:

In the LEFT command, use CHARINDEX on CHAR(13) to find the position of the first line feed character, as in the following example:

```
declare @a table(id int identity(1,1) not null, lines text); --Source
declare @b table(id int identity(1,1) not null, lines text); --Target

insert into @a(lines) values ('1111111'+char(13)+char(10)+'222222')
insert into @b(lines) values ('aaaaa');

update b
set lines=LEFT(cast(a.lines as varchar(max)),CHARINDEX(char(13),cast(a.lines as varchar(max)),1)-1)+cast(b.lines as varchar(max))
from @a a
join @b b on a.id=b.id;

select * from @b;
```

I suggest also updating your TEXT data types to varchar(max), if possible. varchar(max) is much more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do a `substring` or `left` till the first newline of the text field.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily assign this via subquery for use in insert or update statements.

```
SELECT  ( CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), action_Item.Description) = 0
           THEN action_Item.Description
           ELSE SUBSTRING(action_Item.Description, 0,
                          CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), action_Item.Description))
      END ) AS [Description] FROM    action_Item
```

Where I am selecting the first line if "Description" field from a table called "action_Item"

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @crlf   char(2);

SET     @crlf = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

UPDATE  table1
SET     LEFT(table2.fieldWithCRLF, CHARINDEX(table2.fieldWithCRLF, @crlf, 0) - 1) + table1.fieldToPrepend
FROM    table1
        INNER JOIN table2
            ON  table1.sharedKey = table2.sharedKey
WHERE   CHARINDEX(table2.fieldWithCRLF, @crlf, 0) > 0
```